# Подвисает каталог при переходе на другую страницу или использовании фильтра

Tags: opencart

Друзья, помогите советом - подвисает каталог при переходе на другую страницу или использовании фильтра... опенкарт 3.0.2.0

Comment: Ссылку на сайт дайте....

Comment: Никакого подвисания не замечаю. Если вы имеете ввиду, что при переходе на страницу это происходит не сразу, то смотрите в сторону оптимизации сайта. Я вижу задержку в ответе сервера в 1.5 секунду. Как минимум нужно поставить кеш.

Comment: Нет, не при переходе на какую-то другую страницу - а при переходе на 2 страницу каталога или при нажатии на какой-либо из параметров фильтра.

Comment: Загляните в консоль браузера. При фильтрации или пагинации: 
`jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 Failed to load httpss://coolnature.biz/index.php?route=product/ocfilter/category&path=21&filter=28,28,28: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`
браузер пытается ссылку с httpss загрузить. Я полагаю какие-то правки делали для перехода на https...

Comment: Упс..Спасибо большое)